# Is it safe to use the HTML5 button element for production websites?

Tags: html, cross-browser, forms

Is it still worth using the traditional `input` element for buttons or can I start to use the HTML5 button right away?

I have been able to verify that the `button` element works on the following, but are there any issues that I need to be aware of?

- IE9 (3 modes from F12 tools)

  - IE9 with IE9 standards
  - IE8 with IE8 standards
  - IE7 with IE7 standards
- Chrome 13
- Firefox 4
- Safari 5

*Note: I am not supporting IE6-, I am interested in IE7+, Chrome, Safari, FireFox, Opera, etc.*

Comment: The `button` element has been around long before html 5.  As long as you don't rely on the new html 5 attributes, you should be fine.

Comment: As far as I know the button tag was present also in HTML 4.0, so it should be compatible with older browsers which supported HTML4.

Comment: @Sam @Jose interesting, I have just looked up the html4 spec and its right there. I have only seen it being used of recent so I assumed it was new. Why do people tend to use the `input` element instead?

Comment: I personally stick with all inputs for consistency... It's annoying having the 1 odd form element which isn't self-closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I say use the `button` element as you then also get free accessibility via the keyboard with it, which can be handy.

Plus if it's a button, use the element that's made for it!